# How to get filename on file chaged event in C++

Tags: c++, file-watcher

I have followed [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx) from MS and it works fine. Now I would like to ask you how to retrieve the filename of the file that was changed in the directory?

Comment: `FindFirstChangeNotification`: *This function does not indicate the change that satisfied the wait condition. To retrieve information about the specific change as part of the notification, use the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` function.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've been notified of a change, you use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to get the actual list of changes. The result will be an array of `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` structures, each one holding a filename and the offset of the next structure.